# Multiple-Choice / Correction program (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, multiple-choice

(Coding JS)

Im trying to code a correction program, applied in some sort of multiple choice quiz - with 3 possible answers (A, B, C)

I obviously need variables (names)

```
var Simon = [A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C]
var (new name) = [.., ..., ..., .. and so on]
```

And some sort of correct string: `[A, B, B, B, C, A , B, C]`

Now if I for example

```
console.log(functionName([A, B, B, A, B, C, C, A, B])
```

I want the output to be lets say: "Simon" because he has the most correct answers (5 correct), the function has to check and match the index of each name/variable.

I started coding not so long ago, so im kinda new (noob). Maybe im over my head already with this sort of challenge...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function, that is executed for every element in an array (f. e. Simon). This function then should compare the current element of that array (Simon) with the correct answers. This could be something like this:

```
var simon = ["A", "C", "B", "D"];
var correctAnswers = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var simonsScore = 0;

// This executes the fuction checkCorrectAnswers for each element in Simon
simon.forEach(checkCorrectAnswers);

alert("Correct Answers: " + simonsScore);

// item is the current item and index is its index
function checkCorrectAnswers(item, index) {
  // Compare the answer with the correct answer
  if(item == correctAnswers[index]) {
        // if they are correct, increase simonsScore
        simonsScore++;
  }

}
```

Edit:

Okay, so if you "just" need the name of the student, then you nees a two dimensional array. The first level array is the "list" of all the students. The second level is the student with their "data". The data is their name, answers and score. So you can do the same as we did above (use forEach to go through the array) but you need to do it on both levels.

The code below logs the student name with the highest score and their score.

Does this work for you?

```
var answers = [["Simon", "A", "C", "B", "D"], ["Bob", "A", "B", "E", "D"]];
var correctAnswers = ["correctAnswers", "A", "B", "C", "D"];
var highestScore = 0;
var highestScoreName = "";

// This executes the fuction checkCorrectAnswers for each element in answers
answers.forEach(compareStudents);
// Log your result
console.log("Most Answers are " + highestScore + " by " + highestScoreName);

// Function ---------------------------------------------------

function compareStudents (item, index, arr) {
// First we create a score variable for each student an push it in their array
  var score = 0;
  arr[index].push(score);

    // Now we check answers for each Student
    arr[index].forEach(checkCorrectAnswers);
 
 // Now their score has been updated in checkCorrectAnswers,
 // so now we can check if their score is higher than the highest score
 // to get the last element of the array thats the current student
  var score = arr[index][arr[index].length-1];

    // and compare it with the highscore
  if(score > highestScore) {
    highestScore = score;
    highestScoreName =  arr[index][0]; // thats where we find the name of the student
  }
  
}

// item is the current item and index is its index, arr is the array we're checking
function checkCorrectAnswers(item, index, arr) {
  // get the current score from the array with is the last element and save it
  var score = arr[arr.length-1];
  arr.pop();
  
  // compare the answwer with the correct one
  // (the first element compared will be their name compared with "correctAnswers", which will never be true)
  if(item == correctAnswers[index]) {       
        score++;
      console.log("Correct answer: " +item + " = " + correctAnswers[index] + ". Total of " + score + " correct answers.");
  }
  
  // Push the score into the array, so the last element is always the score
  arr.push(score);
  
}
```

Comment: Aight, I've looked into it - and I really appriciate your time! I understand "most" of it, but what if I wanted to output the name that has the most correct answers?